# MSYS - open a file as a separate process

Tags: windows, bash, terminal

When I open a file in MSYS, i.e. `subl init.js` the terminal hangs until I quit that process. Is there a way to run it as a separate process like in Mac terminal?

Comment: add a & at the end of the command to run it in the background - assuming it's a standard shell such as bash

Comment: Thanks that works great. If you make that an answer I can tick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSYS shell is a standard unix-like shell such as bash, so if you want to run programs in the background on the shell, you need to put an `&` at the end of the command. This causes it to run in the background.

I would recommend reading [this SuperUser question about Shell Tutorials](https://superuser.com/questions/25486/bash-shell-tutorials), which has some excellent links to shell tutorials and resources.